# What feature of Scala allows for Props[SomeActor] syntax

Tags: scala, akka

One aspect of Akka I've always just glossed over appears right in the canonical Hello World! example. That is, the syntax for creating a `Props` class:

```
val props = Props[MyActor]
```

**Q.** What mechanism in Scala is allowing for the type parameter (i.e. `[MyActor]`) to be specified in this way? I'm assuming this gets translated to a constructor/apply method on `Props` that takes a `Class` parameter? For instance, my guess is it's equivalent to:

```
val props = Props(classOf[MyActor])
```

I've always assumed `classOf` was "special" and somehow cheated in order to use the `[]` syntax. Since I see that Akka, a 3rd party library, utilizes the same syntax it would be great to see a simple REPL example that demonstrates how I can utilize this syntax for my own classes.

Comment: `object Props` has a apply method of the signature `def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag]()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instances of Props are ultimately of the following case class (https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0511b07f3e50e0422379075ae76dd158e4d377fa/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Props.scala#L115):

```
final case class Props(deploy: Deploy, clazz: Class[_], args: immutable.Seq[Any])
```

Since this is a case class, scala will generate default `apply` method of

```
Props.apply(deploy: Deploy, clazz: Class[_], args: immutable.Seq[Any])
```

The `Props` companion object has several other `apply` methods which create instances of this class for you, using the default apply method. In the case of `Props[MyActor]`, this is the method:

```
def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](): Props = apply(defaultDeploy, implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass, List.empty)
```

`Props[MyActor]` is syntactic sugar for `Props.apply[MyActor]()`. So `Props` is using the reflection capabilities of `ClassTag` in order to get the runtime class of `MyActor`, so it can satisfy the parameter `clazz: Class[_]` of the `Props` case class.

Comment: Ahh yes! Intersting. I haven't researched `ClassTag`. Looks like it's using `implicitly` to do the magics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is the Scala `ClassTag` mechanism. For instance:

```
object Test {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](s: String): Option[T] = ...
}

val foo = Test[Foo]("foo")
```

In the `apply` method you can simply do something like

```
val ctor = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.getConstructors.head
```

in order to get access to the first constructor of `T` for example.